# Twitter Streaming API error in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am using [140dev Twitter Database Server (PHP)](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/) this following code as I  was getting the error  in get_tweet.php

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in \htdocs\140dev\db\get_tweets.php on line.

Please help me out

Comment: The error refers to a line in the script, can we see it - and the script.

Comment: @Dagon I am using this script https://github.com/fennb/phirehose

Comment: i see no get_tweets.php file, nor have you given us the full error message

Comment: @Dagon http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/get-tweets-php/ use this code I didn't even edit this code.

Comment: @Dagon have you check the code or I should paste the code here itself?

Comment: I think it's likely that you are trying to connect to something and the connection isn't working. Maybe a firewall in the way, or perhaps safe_mode is enabled on your server, and external fetches are prohibited? Is this on a local or remote server?

Comment: @halfer local server as it work on different port as in my college port is blocked

Comment: ^ Err, didn't quite follow that. If you know you've a firewall in the way, speak to your network admin, or try it at home on an unfirewalled connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script exceeded the maximum time alloted for a script to run (30 seconds by default). See [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in your configuration (php.ini) file.

You may not want to change your current settings, as the problem could be in the script itself. It may be that your script is dragging out due to its design. Without having more details we cannot say.

Additionally, the problem could have been with twitter (though probably not too likely). However, if your script is waiting 30 seconds to get a response from Twitter, that would seem to me like a design problem in the script itself.

Comment: wouldn't fixing why the script uses an  *excessive* amount of time be a better solution?

Comment: +1 @Dagon Absolutely, which is why I went on to say say that. I'm not suggesting the solution is to modify the ini file. I'm only explaining the source of the message the OP received.

Comment: @Dagon Yes, but in my defense, none of the edits suggested changing the `max_execution_time` is the solution.

Comment: @JonathanSampson It didn't work...again same error I think stream.twitter.com not work right now is it correct

Comment: @John What didn't work? I pointed to the source of the message. If you attempted to change your `max_execution_time` value, you would need to restart Apache/IIS in order to see these changes. Without downloading the project and launching it locally, I cannot comment on the code.

Comment: I have restart my Apache but now error Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded...you can download from http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/download/ as I have no dedicated server for uplaoding